# Why can you integrate on both sides of an equation?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have seen that you can integrate on both sides of an equation but that can't differentiate both sides of an equation. For differentiation it is easy to find examples why it doesn't work, but I haven't found a proof for why you can integrate on both sides of an equation. So, does anybody know a proof?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*equation*" here. Some examples would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You certainly can differentiate equations, in the following sense: differentiation is an operation on functions, and if two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ are equal, then $f'=g'$. What you can't do is conclude that $f'(x)=g'(x)$ just from the fact that $f(x)=g(x)$ for some given $x$. But is this really surprising? After all, you can't conclude that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal just by knowing that that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a matter of proof or disproof. It’s a matter of understanding what equality means, and what integration and differentiation do.

**The very first thing I want to clear up is that you don’t integrate or differentiate equations! You also don’t integrate/differentiate the left-hand side of an equation or the right-hand side of an equation! The things we integrate/differentiate are functions!**

For the sake of avoiding technicalities, assume all the functions are “nice enough”. If I have a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ and I have a function $g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, and I tell you that $f=g$, then of course it must follow that $f’=g’$ and that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $\int_0^xf=\int_0^xg$. That is literally what the definition of equality of functions guarantees. The operations of integration/differentiation depend on the function you consider, so if you don’t change the function then of course the result doesn’t change.

On the other hand, an equation, while it expresses an equality, it doesn’t necessarily mean it is the equality of functions. For example, $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$ is an equation, but there are no functions to speak of. This simply expresses the equality of two sets. Next, and probably more along the lines of what you may have heard, is an equation say for instance $x^2=1$ (where $x\in\Bbb{R}$). From this you of course cannot conclude that “by differentiation $2x=0$”. Why not? Well, you shouldn’t blindly do symbolic manipulations and apply formulas. You need to ask yourself what the equation is actually saying. The equation $x^2=1$ is simply saying that $x$ is a real number such that if I multiply by itself then the result is $1$. The only possibilities are then $x=-1$ or $x=1$. There are no functions anywhere here!

If you wanted to, you could consider the two functions $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, defined as $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=1$, i.e the squaring function and the constant function with value $1$. Then, the above computation says that $\{x\in\Bbb{R}\,: f(x)=g(x)\}=\{-1,1\}$, i.e there are only two real numbers where the outputs of the two functions are equal, namely $f(-1)=g(-1)=1$ and $f(1)=g(1)=1$. For any other value of $x$, we have $f(x)\neq 1=g(x)$. So, clearly, the two functions $f,g$ are not the same. So, why would we ever expect $f’=g’$ (once again, don’t get things mixed up here: does there exist a value of $x$ such that $f’(x)=g’(x)$? Yes, we have $f’(0)=g’(0)=0$… but does this in any way say that $f’$ is the same function as $g’$? Absolutely not!)? Same thing with integrals: why would we expect $\int_0^xf=\int_0^xg$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$? The answer is we don’t, and it is in fact false in general.